# CMS pages have become duplicated?

Tags: sections

I have overtaken a project and noticed that the pages section of the CMS shows duplications.

I have not come up against this before and was wondering if anyone has any suggestions to stop two of them showing at once.

The fist duplicate shows like a Channel:

[image]

The Second enters the page (acting like a single):

[image]

Both are for the home page and both work in updating the home page.

Any suggestions here would be of great help -
Thanks - W

Comment: What plugins is the site using? Is your Craft CMS install up-to-date? You might be using the [Expanded Singles](https://plugins.craftcms.com/expanded-singles) plugin?

Comment: Hi - thanks for your help - yes there was a plugin being used to alter the appearance of the site. I will update and remove :)